# How to sort list of lists by an integer in the lists inside

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
biglist = [['Bob', 10], ['Karl', 12], ['Judy', 11]]

customsort(biglist)
```

Should return this:

```
biglist = [['Bob', 10],  ['Judy', 11], ['Karl', 12]]
```

Comment: It is based on `Bob` before `Judy` before `Karl`, or on `10` before `11` before `12`, or both? If both, which has precedence?

Comment: Is the integer (according to your recent title edit) always the second element?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Yes it is sir

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> biglist = [['Bob', 10], ['Karl', 12], ['Judy', 11]]
>>> sorted(biglist, key=lambda x:x[1])
[['Bob', 10], ['Judy', 11], ['Karl', 12]]
```

Comment: Why not just `sorted(biglist)`?